# Load data infile in mysql not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, csv

i am using the mysql LOAD DATA INFILE, to insert values from csv file to database table.
but here i am using this LOAD DATA INFILE statement in run.sql file, and the t.csv file is also there with run.sql.

When i  run the run.sql this line is causing error.if i give the entire path with.csv file name. then it is inserting the values to tables.

how to make it relative path?

`LOAD DATA INFILE 't.csv' INTO TABLE movie FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';`

sample from t.csv

```
,Bulls,dsda
,Bulls,rest
,Bulls,ests
,Bulls,rsts
,Bulls,rets
```

error message

```
ERROR 29 (HY000) at line 112: File '/var/lib/mysql/t.csv' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

Comment: If you don't show the error message how do you expect to get any help?  Also, post the table definition and a sample of the input CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relative filename is interpreted relative to the current working directory when the client program was started, as mentioned in [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/load-data.html).

If you did not start the client in `/var/lib/mysql` the file will not be found.